# How to make a CSS sprite use a different image the longer the value "stays"?

Tags: css, css-sprites

For instance, the longer someone is say, holding the mouse button or using an arrow key, change the image differently. Say a walking animation. When the user holds for say, the right arrow key, the walking animation appears. But there are multiple images in the sprite that you must use over a little time.
If it's a little vague, I can't help it. It's hard to explain.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not too difficult to achieve. First apply a listener on the arrow key...

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) example.

```
$("document").ready(function() {

   $(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
             case 13:
                // Perform some action when enter is placed
             return;
             case 37:
                // animate left
                animate.dir = 'left';
                animate.moving = true;
                animate.anim();
             break;
             case 38:
                 // animate up
              break;
             case 39:
                 // animate right
                 animate.dir = 'right';
                animate.moving = true;
                animate.anim();
              break; 
             case 40:
                 // animate down
              break;   
        }
    }).on('keyup', function(){
        animate.reset();
    });
});

var animate = {
    moving:false,
    speed: 100,
    dir: 'right',
    frame_width: 100,
    cur_position: 0,
    queue: null,
    anim: function(){
        if(this.moving)
        {
            if(dir == 'right')
                this.cur_position -= this.frame_width;
            else
                this.cur_position += this.frame_width; 

            $('#guy').css({backgroundPosition: this.cur_position + 'px 0' });

            this.queue = setTimeout(function(){
                this.anim();
            }, this.speed);
        }
    },
    reset: function(){
        this.moving = false;
        clearTimeout(animate.queue);
        this.cur_position = 0;
        $('#guy').css({backgroundPosition: '0 0' });
    }
};

html:

<div id="guy"></div>

css:

#guy{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: url(/image.png);
    background-position:0 0;
}
```

I can't promise anything with this untested code but the general idea is correct. I've handled tons of user interaction based sprite animations.

The thing to remember is to have your animation call itself recursively while animate.moving == true. then on keyup you clear that timeout. With that basic thing in mind you can control the actions of animate.anim() however you choose. In this case I simply remove or add 100 pixels to the x-offset in background-position. That assumes your sprite is a horizontal image with each frame being 100 x 100 pixels.

**IN ADDITION** this code does NOT consider when the image should loop. So you will have to calculate this based on your image dimensions and the loop for each particular animation. If you get my example working, it should be trivial to apply the loop listener when needed. Simply post a question to this answer if you get that far and don't know what to do. I would write it here but really, you could write volumes on animation handling and I'd rather do it on demand than on speculation.

You can view source of one of my test domains animation fx on rollover and out:

http://www.wrightonwrong.com

Answer (score 0):

You could always use an animated gif and then just make a sprite file and use it as usual.